# Tooltip hover on radio buttons with different text on each buttons in Angular

Tags: angular

I have three radio buttons (I use Ngfor) and I want different hovering text on each button. How can go about it?

Here is what I have tried:

```
<div *ngFor="let radio of masses,let i = index;" class="col-0 mt-3 ml-4">
      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
         <input [(ngModel)]="masses.name"
                         #masses="ngModel"
                         [value]="radio.id"
                         class="form-check-input"
                         id="masses{{radio.id}}"
                         name="masses"
                         required type="radio">
 <label class="form-check-label"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="[radio.id][i]=='0' ? 'this test': 'Trying' " for="masses{{radio.id}}">{{radio.name}}</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if it is the text itself or the style of the text you want different. If it is the text itself, you can use mattooltip (https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/overview)

```html
<div *ngFor="let radio of masses,let i = index;" class="col-0 mt-3 ml-4">
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input [(ngModel)]="masses.name" 
               #masses="ngModel"  
               **[matTooltip]="radio.name"**
               [value]="radio.id"
               class="form-check-input"
               id="masses{{radio.id}}"
               name="masses"
               required type="radio">

        <label class="form-check-label" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="[radio.id][i]=='0' ? 'this test': 'Trying' " for="masses{{radio.id}}">{{radio.name}}</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yh, the text(title) of each radio button should be defferent.

Comment: Then you can use matToolTip as mention above :)

Comment: you can find more information on how to add material to your project here
https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started